# Zend Data Mapper design

Tags: php, zend-framework, design-patterns, datamapper

I'm using Zend Framework and following the design pattern of separating the Data layer from the Domain layer
the problem raises when implementing the methods for the Data mapper 
so i implemented the `save()` which insert & update based on whether domain model contains id property and `find()` which return the records domain object based on id parameter
but what if i need to

1. search all/some rows in a table and return all the columns
2. search the same rows and return a mysql COUNT value

should i just directly use the class the inherited the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract for these needs or
should i implement method for every need ?

i'm a little confused on how to divide the functionality of the Data Mapper that will fit my needs and my future needs

Comment: can you please review the answers you have been given and either accept the one that helped you most/solved your problem or point out why none of the answers solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add individual finder Methods, e.g.

```
class PersonMapper
{
    … // other code

    public function findByLastName()
    {
        // … fetch rowset and map them
    }

    public function countByLastName() 
    {
    …
```

However, that will quickly get out of hand when you need to query multiple columns or want to handle CRUD by arbitrary criteria. You don't want methods like

```
 public function findByLastNameAndBirthdayAndMaritalStatus()
```

The easy solution would be to use `Zend_Db_Table_Select` to create the queries and then pass those to the Data Mapper to execute and map them, e.g. in your DataMapper

```
public function getSelect()
{
    return $this->personTable->select();
}

public function findBy(Zend_Db_Table_Select $select)
{
    $people = $this->personTable->fetchAll($select);
    // map people to People objects
}
```

You could abstract this further with the Mapper returning and accepting PersonQueryBuilder instead, which hides the SQL Semantics inside and let's you specify against your Domain Objects instead. It's more effort though.

Also have a look at the Repository and Specification Pattern.

Comment: woudnt having the user get an instance of Zend_Db_select from the mapper and then returning it back to the mapper violates the whole

Comment: @Xeus only to some extent. Zend_Db_Table_Select is an abstract query builder, so you dont have a direct coupling to a specific RDBMS. However, the API semantic of Zend_Db_Table_Select is of course db related. That's what the suggested Query Builder could solve, because it would allow you to query your Domain Objects on the basis of how your Domain models are structured. However, the required effort to implement such a Query Builder is much higher. ZF doesnt provide that out of the box. It's a matter of what is good enough.

Comment: @Gordon, could you perhaps clarify: (1) do `getSelect()` and `findBy(Select $select)` go in the mapper? (2) i presume `$this->personTable` is a table data gateway which handles well single tables. but what if there are multiple joins involved? Is it ok to put a couple of `Select`s into the mapper? (3) `findBy(Select $select` handles only persons. what if i need to pass either of the 3 `Select`s, say `PersonSelect()`, `PlaceSelect()`, `ValueSelect()`. should i put the logic mapping the data to the corresponding object in the same mapper, or create multiple mappers using the strategy pattern?

Comment: @DimaDz I dont have strong a opinion about this nowadays. Put stuff where it makes sense to you (consider the GRASP principles for this) but first and foremost make the code work within reasonable effort.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks very much, gordon. it's always about the compromise between the working code and the time spent on it.

Answer (score 0):

As much as Gordon very likely has the correct answer, I find it overly complex for my tastes and needs at the moment.

I use a base mapper class for all of my domain mappers and I put as much functionality into the base class as I can.

I use a find by column method that works fairly well in all of my mappers:

```
//from abstract class Model_Mapper_Abstract

//The constructor of my base class accepts either a dbtable model
// or the name of a table stored in the concrete mapper tablename property. 
 public function __construct(Zend_Db_Table_Abstract $tableGateway = null)
    {   
        if (is_null($tableGateway)) {   
            $this->tableGateway = new Zend_Db_Table($this->tableName);
        } else {    
            $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        }
    }
/**
 * findByColumn() returns an array of entity objects
 * filtered by column name and column value.
 * Optional orderBy value.
 *
 * @param string $column
 * @param string $value
 * @param string $order optional
 * @return array of entity objects
 */
public function findByColumn($column, $value, $order = null)
    {
        //create select object
        $select = $this->getGateway()->select();
        $select->where("$column = ?", $value);
        //handle order option
        if (!is_null($order)) {
            $select->order($order);
        }
        //get result set from DB
        $result = $this->getGateway()->fetchAll($select);
        //turn DB result into domain objects (entity objects)
        $entities = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            //create entity, handled by concrete mapper classes
            $entity = $this->createEntity($row);
            //assign this entity to identity map for reuse if needed
            $this->setMap($row->id, $entity);
            $entities[] = $entity;
        }
        //return an array of entity objects
        return $entities;
    }
```

I hope you find this useful as an idea generator at the least. Also if you wish to implement a `SQL Count()` statement in a method similar to this it will go easier if you use [Zend_Db_Expr()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.columns-expr) when you build that select().